# get sql error code in code behind in asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

So, I am getting an exception in Stored Procedure whose error code is 547. I have created a data diagram in sql server, where I have defined the relationships.when I run the any delete SP I get an error saying FK conflict, which is right. My problem is how do I get the number(i.e 547) in my C# code.

```
catch (Exception ex)
        {

            lblMessage.Text = ex.Message;
        }
```

I sthere any way where I can get this 547 code in my C# code.? Like

```
 ex.somethin (which gives me the error message's code).
```

Answer (score 4):

Try This.

```
    try
    {

    }
    catch(SqlException ex)
    {
        lblMessage.Text = ex.Message;
    }
```

Comment: but what if I get an exception other than sql exception.? Can I not use Exception and still get error code.?

Answer (score 2):

Multiple catches can be used:

```
 try
        {

        }
      catch(SqlException sqlex)
        {
          if(sqlex.Number ==547)
               {
                   //code
               }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            lblMessage.Text = ex.Message;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using Elmah library (Error Logging Modules And Handlers)

Here is a step by step tutorial on how to use it: http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/deployment/deploying-web-site-projects/logging-error-details-with-elmah-cs

Comment: Related to this: Take a look at https://bitbucket.org/wasp/elmahr/wiki/Home. This is a dashboard to observe errors in your applications in realtime and does not require you to implement more then Elmah into your application. Comes in real handy!

Answer (score 1):

For more details http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlexception.aspx

```
 try
 {
   ... 
   ...
 }
 catch(SqlException ex)
 {
    lblMessage.Text = ex.Message;
 }
```